# Incrementar valores em objetos

Tags: javascript

```
let items = [
  { prod: '', qty: 50, vUnit: 5 },
  { prod: '', qty: 10, vUnit: 20 },
  { prod: '', qty: 5, vUnit: 10 },
];
let mail = [
  { name: 'Joãozinho', email: 'joao@hotmail.com', value: null },
  { name: 'Mariazinha', email: 'maria@outlook.com.br', value: null },
  { name: 'Lindomar', email: 'lindomar@gmail.com', value: null },
];
let addQty = () => {
  let total = items.reduce(function getTotal(total, item) {
    return total + item.qty * item.vUnit;
  }, 0);
  return total;
};
let mailDelivery = () => {
  mail.forEach(({ email, value }) => {
    console.log(
      email +
        ' deve pagar ' +
        Intl.NumberFormat('pt-br', {
          style: 'currency',
          currency: 'BRL',
        }).format(value / 100),
    );
  });
};
function sharedValue() {
  clients = mail.length;
  let total = addQty();
  let shared = total / clients;
  mail.map((x) => {
    x.value = parseInt(shared);
  });
  if (total === parseInt(shared) * clients) {
    return mailDelivery();
  } else {
    diff = total - parseInt(shared) * clients;
    //Aqui não faço ideia de como continuar

    return mailDelivery();
  }
}
sharedValue();
```

Tenho os dois objetos e tenho as seguintes situações:

- calcular a soma dos valores, ou seja, multiplicar o preço de cada item por sua quantidade e somar todos os itens
- Dividir o valor de forma igual entre a quantidade de e-mails

Só que entra o seguinte ponto:

- Quando fizer a divisão, é importante que não falte nenhum centavo! Por exemplo, um valor total de R$ 1,00 para ser dividido entre 3 e-mails. Isso daria uma dízima infinita. No entanto, o correto aqui é que duas pessoas fiquem com o valor 0,33 e a terceira fique com 0,34.

Minha ideia foi, retornar a diferença entre o valor total e a soma dos valores divididos entre os clientes, porém, não faço a minima ideia de como poderia estar incrementando esse valor em "mail.value" e subtraindo da diferença obtida...

Comment: Não sei se isto responde à seu pergunta mas pode adicionar a diferença, por exemplo, ao último: `mail[mail.length - 1].value += diff;`.

Comment: Pensei em algo assim também meu mano, só que tipo, quando entra naquele ponto de "No entanto, o correto aqui é que duas pessoas fiquem com o valor 0,33 e a terceira fique com 0,34.", no código que montei a diff seria igual a 2, nisso teria que dividir igualitariamente esses 2 sendo 1 para o indice 0 e 1 para o indice 1 da array

Comment: Veja a minha resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer um pequeno loop e distribuir o valor de diff. Qualquer coisa como:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= diff; i++) {
  mail[mail.length - i].value ++;
}
```

Comment: MANO DO CÉU, salvou lindamente, fiquei pensando em mil modos mas era só ir no básico mesmo kkkkkkkkkk